# Snowflake is giving me the error "SAML response is invalid or matching user is not found. Contact your local system administrator"

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have an Azure Active directory with SSO and provisioning enabled. Users from my company can SSO into snowflake just fine, but when I invite a user from GMail or another domain into our AD they get the SAML error. The Snowflake AD app has provisioned the user to Snowflake correctly from what I can see.

How do I troubleshoot this?

Thanks,
Phil

Comment: Does the NameID attribute being passed from the IDP match the Login_Name that is set for users in Snowflake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@suzy_lockwood It was the NameID attribute giving me the problem. I linked it back to the Snowflake Application in my Azure AD. The fix was to go to Manage > Single-Sign On > User Attributes and Claims. Under Required Claim I opened the claim "Unique User Identifier (Name ID) and changed the source attribute from UPN to be user.mail. 
[image: SSO - User Attributes and Claims]

Answer (score 2):

This error is due to unable to identify the user. Please specify the complete name if the user while authenticating:

```
snowsql -a mytest.us-east-1 -u xyz@abc.com
```